# Creating Custom Breadcrumbs For Moodle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, moodle

Dear friends, I'm making a custom breadcrumb for Moodle 3.3 according to this Example "[Click Here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/breadcrumb-hr-horizontal-rule)", But having problems, style not applied (I'm adding this code in Moodle custom CSS box). I tried other simple variants and they worked perfectly, but I need this version... 
I think it needs some modifications for Moodle. I searched the web, but couldn't be solved this.
Please Help / Suggest what to change, how to make this to work.

Thank you In Advanced!

Comment: show your code first. so we can see what you've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I testes some variant's ... Here is the code: `

```
hr {
  height: 4px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom:-3px;
}

.hr-primary{
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(66,133,244,.8), rgba(66, 133, 244,.6), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}

.breadcrumb {
  background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0); 
  border: 0px solid rgba(245, 245, 245, 1); 
  border-radius: 20px; 
  display: block;
}

.btn{
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size: 12px; 
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

`